# How to find generators of translation subgroup of an abstract reflection (coxeter) group

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, reflection, coxeter-groups

I have an infinite reflection group https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_group

Take for example the affine groups $[4,4],[4,3,4],[4,3,3,4]$...

I'd like to get an explicit expression for generators that generate the translation subgroup:
$$T=\langle t_1,\cdots,t_r \; :\; t_i t_j = t_j t_i\rangle $$ and each $t_i$ has infinite order.

For example for [4,4] : $t_1=r_1r_2r_3; t_2=r_3r_2r_1$;

[Edit : per Derek Holt's comment $t_1=r_2r_3r_2r_1; t_2=r_3r_2r_1r_2;$ is the appropriate example]

What about others in general? I'm sure this is a known result but I can't find it.

Comment: In your example, $t_1=t_2^{-1}$, so that cannot be right. I think you want $t_1 = r_2r_3r_2r_1$, $t_2=r_3r_2r_1r_2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt : you're right. I checked that $t_1 <> t_2$ but I should have added $t_1 <> t_2^{-1}$...the above was found by search using gap

Comment: Are you assuming that your Coxeter group is finitely generated and virtually abelian? (There is a more general notion of affine Coxeter groups which are not virtually abelian.)

Comment: @MoisheKohan : the groups are finitely generated. I don't have any other restrictions; I'm also interested in non-affine infinite groups if they also have such subgroups.